# How to inject a service as dependency for a custom filter in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a custom filter to track events. So the filter can call methods on the segmentio service.

```
angular.module('sageApp')
  .filter('trackEvent', function(segmentio) {
    return function(entry, category) {
     segmentio.track(entry, category);
    }
});
```

But the segmentio service is not available. Any ideas on how to dependency inject a service to a filter woule be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the above code works.

Comment: If you minify the code it may cease to work (because the param name changes), which is why the [square bracketed] format in the accepted answer exists.  It's called Inline Array Annotation and you can read more about it at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 49):

Try:

```
app.filter('sageApp', ['segmentio', function(segmentio) {
    return function(entry, category) {
        segmentio.track(entry, category);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: How will you now write a test for _sageApp_ that injects a mock _segmentio_

Comment: Just check if the appropriate method is being called on segmentio mock service you inject.

Comment: @SatheeshKumar How do you mock the filter's dependencies? I can't seem to pass in mocks when instantiating a filter ( `$filter('name')` doesn't accept other arguments).

Answer (score 3):

The service is tested and works. Acutally I found out my issue, when using angular, sometimes chrome dev tools doesn't display the variables in the closure when you put a debugger in to inspect . When I did console.log(segmentio) it worked fine.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. You cannot see anything that is not used in a function scope, even though you would intuitively assume that you could inspect a variable outside the function, in this case, inside `return function(...`. But once you write dumy code like `var temp = segmentio`, you will have something to inspect.